# How to intercept logs from a different ActorSystem in scala.testkit.eventfilter?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have a Scala class `ComponentBuilder` which deals with creating actors and initializing them. It has a field `system` corresponding to the `ActorSystem` (among other things).

Now, I'd like to test it using `TestKit` - intercept logs which actors produce and check them. If I try to use regular `EventFilter` I can see the log which my actors produce in stdout, but the `EventFilter` doesn't catch them, I guess because they are in a different `ActorSystem`.

One solution I thought of was to make `ComponentBuilder` a subclass of `ActorSystem` and pass all the `AS`-commands to its field. I didn't manage to do it, due to protected methods that return `InternalActorRef`, but anyway I'm not sure if it'll work then, as there will be 2 actor systems anyway.

I also tried to pass some messages from testing class to the actor and wait and check the results. This results in replying to the `deadLetters`, probably for the same reason - the inner `ActorSystem` doesn't know about the outer one.

I will appreciate any solution you may have.

Comment: Maybe a bit convoluted, but you can go out of akka completely: configure your logger to point to your custom "logging" class/singleton, and you can simply store in it the last n logs received, divided by level, and then you can query / test that?

Comment: any success with this?